# Sum of all children cols also when there is no child

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a MySQL table `products`, which looks like this:

```
|--------------------|
| id | parent | sold |
|--------------------|
| 1  | 0      | 1    |
| 2  | 1      | 3    |
| 3  | 1      | 0    |
| 4  | 0      | 2    |
|--------------------|
```

I want to get a result of how many times a product was sold. It has to SUM all of product's children `sold` column too. So I tried to use query like this:

```
SELECT
    p1.id,
    SUM(p2.sold) + p1.sold AS sold
FROM products p1
JOIN products p2
    ON p2.parent = p1.id
WHERE p1.parent = 0;
```

But I get this:

```
|-----------|
| id | sold |
|-----------|
| 1  | 4    |
|-----------|
```

So it works good for first record, because it has children, but fourth record has no children. My expected result is this:

```
|-----------|
| id | sold |
|-----------|
| 1  | 4    |
| 4  | 2    |
|-----------|
```

Comment: MySQL before version 8.0 does not implement hierarchical queries. What version are you using? Alternatively, you could use MariaDB that already does.

Comment: Oh, sorry, wrong tag, I have a Mariadb - 10.1.13-MariaDB

Comment: You are close but not there yet. I think you would need MariaDB 10.2.2 to do this using SQL. I guess your only option is to get all the rows and process them in your application.

Comment: That wouldn't be good if there is like 10k records and jsut want to get "top 12 sold"... so upgrading MariaDB should help?

Comment: See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/with/. It does implement **recursive** in 10.2.2

Comment: @TheImpaler thanks, but YogeshSharma's answer solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `subquery` :

```
select id, sum(sold) +
           ( select coalesce(sum(p1.sold), 0)
             from products p1
             where p1.parent = p.id
           ) as sold
from products p
where parent = 0
group by id;
```

Comment: I'm at a lost on this one. Doesn't this solution cover two levels only?

Comment: Actually children will not have other children, only top records (parents) will have this ability, so I don't have to go "deeper".

Comment: Ah... my bad. I thought it was a multi-level join.

Answer (score 1):

Make it a left outer join, and change null values to 0, so the sum won't null out.

```
SELECT
    p1.id,
    SUM(COALESCE(p2.sold,0)) + p1.sold AS sold
FROM products p1
LEFT JOIN products p2
    ON p2.parent = p1.id
WHERE p1.parent = 0
GROUP BY p1.id;
```

As noted, this solution does not handle multiple levels of children.

[Live demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6c67d/6/0)

Comment: Thanks, but I still haven't get result for 4th row.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
select a.id, sum(a.sold+coalesce(b.sold,0)) from products a left join(
select parent, sum(sold) sold
from products group by parent) b on a.id=b.parent
where a.parent=0
group by a.id
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I get "undefined function isnuull"

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a `left join` and `group by`:

```
SELECT p1.id,
       (COALESCE(SUM(p2.sold), 0) + p1.sold) AS sold
FROM products p1 LEFT JOIN
     products p2
     ON p2.parent = p1.id
GROUP BY p1.id, p1.sold;
```

You need to be careful about `NULL` values for the parents that have no children.

Comment: @debute . . . It does now.  It didn't have the `coalesce()` when I answered.  It also has an unnecessary aggregation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff. . . May be i though o/p has more `sold` with same id.